# Excel/Google Sheets: Copying data from one cell upon "ISTEXT" condition to another tab and cell

Tags: excel, function, if-statement, google-sheets

I'm working on a Google Sheets "Budget" project with data that will be populated via form entries. What I'm trying to accomplish is the following:

I have data entered dynamically in a tab (Debit), If the description in the line entry is "Credit", I want the adjacent cell-value to be placed in another tab/cell.

I have tried many combination of the following all with either errors or not the expected outcome.This may be a case for VBA, of which I have NO experience with.

```
=IF(Debit!B6="Credit",”'Monthly Budget'!C60”,”Fail”)
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B6="Credit",C6 'Monthly Budget'!C60))
=IF(B6="Credit",'Monthly Budget'!C60,"")
```

Please see my screenshot for a visual representation of what I'm trying to accomplish.Thank you in advance.[Graphic Breakdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3w1wp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is all wrong. Please learn the correct syntax.

'Monthly Budget'!C60=

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH ("Credit",Debit!B6)),Debit!C6)
```

- [`SEARCH` syntax](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SEARCH-SEARCHB-functions-9ab04538-0e55-4719-a72e-b6f54513b495)
- DO NOT use `“”`. Always use `"`
- [`IF` Syntax](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en)
- If you want results in a sheet, You do not use need to reference that sheet ( In this case, You don't need to reference monthly budget sheet). But if you want results `from` a sheet, Then you reference that sheet. Here you need to reference B6 and C6 with a sheet name ( `Debit!B6` and `Debit!C6`)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I modified the formulas in so many variations, I think the " " were misplaced. Your answer was most helpful. I was looking at the problem from the wrong angle. Since the cell to be deposited contained the function, I did not need to reference the given cell which accounts for several "Circular Reference" errors received. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it absolutely has, although I'm exploring the same scenario now with searching the Debit!B column for an array of text to prevent me from entering loads of functions. So far this has failed..
'=INDEX(Debit!B5:B17,=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH ("Credit")+1,""),Debit!C6)'

Comment: If this problem is solved, Mark this post as solution by clicking ✔ on the left of the post. If you cannot figure out `INDEX MATCH` , Ask an another question in a different post.